# attributeerror: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'label'

Tags: python, pytorch

Beginner here; I am using *categorical* data on the following code:

```py
train = X_train
targets_numpy = train.label.values
features_numpy = train.loc[:,train.columns != "label"].values/255 # normalization

# train test split. Size of train data is 80% and size of test data is 20%. 
features_train, features_test, targets_train, targets_test = train_test_split(features_numpy,
                                                                              targets_numpy,
                                                                              test_size = 0.2,
                                                                              random_state = 42)
```

And I have received this error:

> attributeerror: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'label'

Any suggestions?

Comment: post full error message

Comment: From your code, it appears that `X_train` is apparently a `numpy.ndarray` (although we can't be sure because you didn't include the definition or import) and on the second line you read `train.label.value` - but since `numpy.ndarray` has no `label` attribute, that fails.

Comment: @Grismar, thank you for your response! Any ideas on how to fix this?